# Is there any filter or material that let only water through not dirt

Tags: drain, drainage, drain-waste-vent, filter, drains

I need a **filter or some kind of cloth material** which only **lets water through and not the dirt** this way I can get filtered water and I can soak it through french drain or dry well.

I just couldn't find anything that I can be rest assured on.

Please help with filter or material name.

Comment: Are you looking for landscaping fabric?  (It won't stop the very fine particles from passing through).

Comment: I'm looking to keep sludge or floating particles from septic tank away of the outlet pipe

Comment: If you want a low maintenance solution and most of the particles are heavy or floating check out *settlement traps/tanks*. You don't have to replace/clean fabrics, just occasionally clean it out. Also depending on your jurisdiction, don't modify your septic tank without checking with any laws. In the US, even within rural areas there are laws governing septic tanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get "drain tile sock" or drain tiles with "sock" installed at just about any place that sells building materials.

These are used where you want to allow the water to pass but block dirt, sand, and gravel.

Comment: Sounds like good one. If I could find something similar for Septic tank outlet pipe , it'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

Talking of cloth material , you can opt for **Nylon Filter Cloth** or **geo text fabric** probably you can find it in local hardware shop or you may buy online

Comment: Geo text fabric sounds like a deal but what's the life time of it for outlet pipe ?

Comment: Not sure about that you may find in shopping site I guess.

Comment: I couldn't find enough information about that besides can biological activity destory the geo text fabric

Comment: I wouldn't worry so much about that. I think geo textile is much more durable I believe